# Processes consistently getting killed for no reason on fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

Several applications/processes are consistently being killed for apparently no reason.

Digging into it, processes are returning signal 9/terminated by SIGKILL. This should happen when memory is low, but I'm monitoring memory and I'm nowhere near running out; this is happening with processes that have a very light memory footprint.

This happens reliably with google-chrome. It exits within 5 seconds of opening, and then returns the message "Killed" to the terminal.

Also confusing is that dmesg doesn't seem to record the event of the process being killed:

[image]

Any advice on what could be the issue would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Edit:
As requested in a comment,
[image]

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema Please [edit] your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our uplink to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: @heynnema, thanks for taking a look, I've added the requested outputs to the post.

Comment: @waltinator You pinged me, instead of the OP. Also... and I've mentioned this before... *"Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our uplink to you."*... strike this line from your scripted comments... thanks!

Comment: Run `google-chrome` in the terminal, let it get killed, then do `top` and show that to me. Also show me `ls -al /var/crash` and `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `sudo lshw -C memory`.

Comment: Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take a few hours to complete.

Comment: @heynnema It seems like this issue might be hardware related, I'm able to completely avoid this issue if I unplug all of my monitors / USB's when I boot into Ubuntu, then re-plug everything back in afterwards.

Comment: Hard to say yet. Please do my last two comments. Report back.

Comment: Which processor? AMD or Intel?

Comment: @heynnema Intel processor. And I can update tomorrow with the output from your other comment.

Comment: @mSours And `memtest`...